# why shutdown report error?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, shutdown

on Linux I tried the steps below:

1. create TCP socket, and connect to any HTTP server
2. send HTTP request data
3. shutdown write with SHUT_WR
4. read from socket to get the HTTP response
5. shutdown read with SHUT_RD
6. close the socket

here error occurred in step 5, with errno=ENOTCONN. The same error hit me when I tried shutdown Write after reading EOF. Is this expected?

Comment: If you get EOF while reading, the connection must have been closed by the server (TCP FIN in the packet carrying the last chunk) - which is perfectly fine for non-persistent connections. I don't think you really need step 5 altogether.

Comment: yep, shutdown read is unnecessary, while it doesn't breach TCP protocol if we do so. Just wondering why tcp stack claim errors?

Comment: Because the connection has gone already. Correlate this to a wire capture, you'll probably see `FIN` coming from the other side before your second `shutdown(2)`.

Comment: FIN is expected, while shutdown read is harmless since it doesn't trigger any TCP packet flow.

Answer (score 0):

In step 4, if you looped on recv() or read() until it returned 0, then you have already consumed the other half of the socket close. Except this time it was initiated by the remote end. That probably explains why step 5 is returning an error - there's nothing to shutdown becuase the remote endpoint has already closed that side of the connection.

In any case, you don't need step 5, because you are closing the socket in step 6. The "close" will shutdown the remaining parts of the TCP connection and close the socket file descriptor.